# JProfiler JDBC probe contains "Select 1 from dual"

Tags: oracle, jpa, profiling, jprofiler

I'm using the JPA/JDBC profiling capababilities of JProfiler. My JavaEE application uses JPA and is backed by an Oracle database.

When I record my application with lots of database requests involved, the probe's result lists `Select 1 from dual` as the most important hot spot. Now I'm wondering,

1. where these statements come from (why they're executed so often) and
2. why they take so long.

My best guess is, that these statements are not executed alone but are **part of an multi insertion** `INSERT ALL`, because those statements always require a `SELECT` part and `Select 1 from dual` is a typical dummy statement.

My questions are:

- Is my assumption right or could these dummy statements come from somewhere else?
- Where is the rest of the statement, this dummy statement is part of?

---

**Update**

I agree that this statement is likely a test statement from the connection pool. I'm currently trying to verify this. If this is true, I would assume that I have no ToDo here, although these statements consume a lot of time. This is because I think they don't block my application but are executed in parallel.

Comment: Presumably, there is a "test on checkout" from your connection pool.

Comment: Why not profiling without INSERTs, but only with DELETEs and SELECTs, to exclude your guess?

Comment: Good point Andrei! Unfortunately, I'm only able to run whole business transactions and during a transaction I always have to persists some entities. But I could run my AppServer in debugging mode and step through. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Elliott Frisch, could you elaborate this a little more please? What is a test on checkout?

Comment: Most connection pool implementations have features to validate the connection, which is being given out or put back. "test on checkout" means, that before giving a connection from the pool away, the pool runs an SQL statement, which does not have any effect (select 1 from dual in case of Oracle) to see if the connection still lives. If the SQL command fails, it is dead. Thats all. See the documentation of your pool implementation.